# Amp-analytics issue

Tags: amp-html, amp-analytics

We've just added amp-analytics to our amphtml pages. Also we've added amp-ad (adsense).
At "Google Analytics" account we receive pageviews stats but on the Publisher-Overview section we got zero stats. Is it a bug with amp-analytics?
Page example: http://womanitely.com/ecofeminism-change-world/amp-list/
Publisher-Overview section screenshot: [Publisher-Overview section screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxt5B.png)

Comment: Probably there is some mistake in connecting two account on GA side?
I mean, everything looks ok on your AMP pages:
1) js libraries are loaded correctly
2) Code of analytics and adsense looks OK too

Comment: What do you mean in "two account"?

Comment: Sorry,.. I meant GA and Adsense accounts